# spreadRadius value as parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, shadow

I am making a global boxShadow list that I want to use in the whole app.
I am trying to pass spreadRadius value(i.e. 5 in the code below) as a parameter to make it dynamic in my custom list of BoxShadow.

Here is the code:

```
List<BoxShadow> outerShadow = [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
    spreadRadius: 5,
    blurRadius: 7,
    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
  )
];
```

Comment: I did not understand what you want?

Comment: @eamirho3ein wanted to use the spreadRadius value to be dynamic, which is defined under BoxShadow()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a method if you wish to pass some data as a parameter.

```
List<BoxShadow> outerShadow(double spreadRadiusVal){
return [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
    spreadRadius: spreadRadiusVal,
    blurRadius: 7,
    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
  )
];
}
```

And use it like

```
boxShadow : outerShadow(5.0),
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new dart file e.g. global_box_shadow.dart

in there write a method which has your parameters as input and returns BoxShadow

```
BoxShadow globalBoxShadow(double spreadRadius){
  return BoxShadow(
    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
    spreadRadius: spreadRadius,
    blurRadius: 7,
    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
  );
}
```

you can know just import this in whatever widget you want and pass this method in as e.g. boxShadow: globalBoxShadow(12.0)